# Random classifier using sklearn dummy classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Using DummyClassifier in Sklearn, the strategy parameter takes different values as described [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.dummy.DummyClassifier.html) in the documentation.

one of them is uniform.

> “uniform”: generates predictions uniformly at random.

What is the meaning of: "generates predictions uniformly"?
is there a difference than predicting the classes using a totally random way, ex. using numpy. random method to generate a list of predictions?

I didn't find any resource describe this strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uniform` option will tend to predict the same number of cases in each class. It is different from the `stratified` option, for instance, which takes into account the classes populations in the training sample.

Comment: If you want to have a look at the source code go to github: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/dummy.py
There you find, that they do exactly what you assume, predicting a random list of predictions from the given classes without using any prior knowledge about their distribution.